# ios push notification with grocer gem in heroku not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, apple-push-notifications

```
PUSHER = Grocer.pusher( certificate: "./config/ck.pem",
    passphrase: ENV['grocer_dev_cert_passphrase'],
  gateway: ENV['grocer_pusher_gateway'],
  port: ENV['grocer_pusher_port'],
  retries: 3
  )

FEEDBACK = Grocer.feedback( certificate: "./config/ck.pem" ,
  passphrase: ENV['grocer_dev_cert_passphrase'],
  gateway: ENV['grocer_feedback_gateway'],
  port: ENV['grocer_feedback_port'] ,
  retries: 3
  )
notification = Grocer::Notification.new(
    device_token: "df67fbd000a631998a46289f798beb75249afc2db0c5ecff2cc83db5b0bf245a",
    alert: "This is God",
    badge: 1,
    sound: 'siren.aiff',
    expiry: Time.now + 60*60,
    content_available: true
    )

PUSHER.push(notification)
```

returning the number of bytes of the alert message by APNS but in Heroku the push notification has not been shown up to the respective devices.Please help me out.thanks in advance.